# [23000][1062] Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, database

when I filled out the database, I received a problem in the form of duplication of the primary key entry, but the fact is that the field "status" field in my database is not the primary key or its part.

### **DB Script**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS travel.`users` (
>   `login` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
>   `password` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
>   `email` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
>   `name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>   `surname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>   `telephone` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
>   `role` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>   `status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
>   `image` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`login`),
>   UNIQUE INDEX `login_UNIQUE` (`login` ASC))
>   ENGINE = InnoDB;
> ```

### **SQL Query**

> ```
> INSERT INTO users VALUES
>   (login = 'admin', password = 'admin', email = 'admin@gmail.com', name = 'Иван',
>    surname = 'Иванов', telephone = '+380674002092', role = 'ADMINISTRATOR', status = '0',
>    image = 'D:/server/admin.img');
>
> INSERT INTO users VALUES
>   (login = 'manager', password = 'manager', email = 'manager@gmail.com', name = 'Петров',
>    surname = 'Пётр', telephone = '+380964002092', role = 'MANAGER', status = '0',
>    image = 'D:/server/manager.img');
> ```

During execution of the second INSERT I receive the following error `[23000][1062] Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: I remove `SQL Server` tag, please do not tag multiple tags that not related to the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
`user_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

you must have a auto increment field.

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove the Column name .Do not need to specify the column.

INSERT INTO users VALUES
  ( 'admin',  'admin', 'admin@gmail.com',  'Иван',
    'Иванов',  '+380674002092',  'ADMINISTRATOR',  '0',
    'D:/server/admin.img');

INSERT INTO users VALUES
  ( 'manager',  'manager',  'manager@gmail.com',  'Петров',
    'Пётр', '+380964002092',  'MANAGER',  '0',
    'D:/server/manager.img');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, after the night of writing code, sometimes there are such commonplace mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Raja's answer is correct, but I want to add few more information for others

**His answer..**

> Remove the Column name .Do not need to specify the column.
>
> `INSERT INTO users VALUES
>     ( 'admin',  'admin', 'admin@gmail.com',  'Иван',
>       'Иванов',  '+380674002092',  'ADMINISTRATOR',  '0',
>       'D:/server/admin.img');`
>
> `INSERT INTO users VALUES
>     ( 'manager',  'manager',  'manager@gmail.com',  'Петров',
>       'Пётр', '+380964002092',  'MANAGER',  '0',
>       'D:/server/manager.img');`

**My additions...**

We do not need to specify the columns if we are doing full insert, if we want to insert data to only some rows, we specify the only columns to that we are inserting in.

Here is a sample,

```
INSERT INTO users(login, password, status) VALUES
  ( 'manager1',  'manager1',  '0');
```

This will insert values only in `login`, `password` and `status` column.

Also, One suggestion, avoid using `varchar` datatype as Primary Key, as it would affect the performance for indexing in main memory. Instead use `int` or `long` (`bigint` in most of RDBMS).

And, you can set that to on `Auto Increment` and it makes easy to use them as `Foreign Key`.

**Here is what you need to change if you want to make it AutoIncrement..**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS travel.`users` (
        `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        `login` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
         ....
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
```